# SQL Syntax error foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb

I've a problem, i try to connect 2 db table, and if I make the query for make a DB structure the answer is Syntax Error.

I paste the code here, somebody can help me ?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS album;
CREATE TABLE `album` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=armscii8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS picture;
CREATE TABLE `picture` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_album` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_album`) REFERENCES album(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=armscii8;
```

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: **Don't say "I got an error". Always say "Here is the error I got" and then show us the exact error.** Don't paraphrase it. Don't retype it. Cut & paste the error message exactly from your screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think your `id_album` must have bean `unsigned`, Same as `id` in `album`

Answer (score 0):

Just add Unsigned in Foreign key line as follows :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS album;
CREATE TABLE `album` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=armscii8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS picture;
CREATE TABLE `picture` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_album` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_album`) REFERENCES album(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=armscii8;
```